# Getting html of an element and excluding elements that are hidden with display: none (and their descendants)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains a load of dynamic HTML. I want to get that HTML in a function, but I don't want to include any elements that have been hidden with display:none. This is complicated slightly by the fact that the user interface to this function is on another tab of the application, and the container div itself is set to display:none when this function is called. Please note that I do not want to modify the contents of the container div itself; only the result of the function.

```
// This returns too much
function getHTMLExceptHidden() {
  return $("#document").html();
}

// This returns null
function getHTMLExceptHidden() {
  return $("#document").filter(["style!='display:none'"]).html()
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempts and any code you have.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a clone of the original dom element so that elements can be removed without affecting the page. Since the clone is not on the page, CSS rules will not be applied to it and therefore elements will be included that are actually hidden on the page. To circumvent this, the checking should be done on the original dom elements, not the clone! This solution recursively checks each element on the page to see if it is hidden with display: block, if so, the corresponding clone node is added to a list for removal. When all the nodes are checked, those hidden are removed from the clone and the remaining html is retrieved from the clone.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/eQohUKo/7/edit)**

```
//get element reference
var $container = $('#myDiv');

//clone element
var $clone = $container.clone();

//find display:none elements of cloned element
var $hidden = findHidden($container, $clone);

//remove display:none elements from clone
$hidden.remove();

//convert clone into html string
var html = $clone.html();

console.log(html);

function findHidden($mainI, $cloneI) {
  var $hidden = $();
  $mainI.children().each(function(i, elem) {
    if ($(this).css('display') === 'none') {
      $hidden = $hidden.add($cloneI.children().eq(i));
    }
    else {
      $hidden = $hidden.add(findHidden($(this), $cloneI.children().eq(i)));
    }
  });
  return $hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the HTML, not an array of elements. And I don't want the result to include any elements that are descendants of hidden elements, even if they are not hidden themselves.

Comment: OK, based on your second example I've come up with this, which seems to work:     function getHTMLExceptHidden() {
      var result = $("#document").clone();
      $(result).find("*").each(function() {
        if($(this).css('display') === 'none') {
          $(this).remove();
        };
      });
      return $(result).html();
    }

Comment: @matthewk the flaw in using `clone()` is that CSS rules won't be applied to it since it's not on the page. See my answer for a cleaner and more accurate solution. I didn't originally know your intentions. You updated question (showing code) is much better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Your code seems to return exactly the same HTML as my function...